# C - Rotate a image by 90 degree (right and left) using one array - bitmap

Tags: c, algorithm, bitmap, rotation

How can I rotate an image by 90 degrees (right and left) a one-dimensional array n-elements?

My array is 24-bits bitmap (NxN)

For example, my array

```
A[16] = {
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
13,14,15,16}
```

rotate to new array:

```
{4,8,12,16
3,7,11,15
2,6,10,14
1,5,9,13}
```

and to:

```
{13,9,5,1,
14,10,6,2,
15,11,7,3,
16,12,8,4}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you figure out where the value in `A[0][0]` should end up? What happens if you swap `A[0][0]` with that cell? What do you need to swap next?

Comment: You need to copy columns of the source array to rows of the target array, or rows of the source array to columns of the target array.  The only issue is which sequence you do things in.  Start by writing a skeletal function that is passed the source and target arrays, and their size.  Then think carefully about how you copy rows into columns.

Comment: You've a mapping from 2D pixel coordinates to 1D array indexes.  Write this out as a function of the coordinates.  Having that, you should also be able to write out an inverse function.  You also have two mappings from 2D coordinates to rotated 2D coordinates -- write these out as functions as well.  The transformation you want is simply a composition of (1D -> 2D), (2D rotation), (2D -> 1D); you have closed form formulae for all of these, so you should be able to write an expression for the overall transform.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`rotation matrix`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). 
The rotation matrix for 90 degrees is simply

```
  [0 -1
  1  0]
```

[here](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-multiply-matrices) you can see how to do matrix multiplication in c if you need.